# How do you wire up states and flows in separate CorDapps for ScheduableState/ScheduableFlow

Tags: corda

We have been following the same framework as in the template (Corda v1.0 onwards) to separate the ContractAndStates and Flow into 2 CorDapps in our development work but ran into some issues when we are using SchedulableFlow. It seems that the SchedulableState and the SchedulableFlow needs to be in the same CorDapp because of the dependencies. We are following the heartbeat CorDapp example to create our ScheduabeState for a cyclic flow to be initiated (https://github.com/joeldudleyr3/heartbeat).

```
override fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity? {
   // A heartbeat will be emitted every second.
   // We get the time when the scheduled activity will occur in the constructor rather than in this method. This is
   // because calling Instant.now() in nextScheduledActivity returns the time at which the function is called, rather
   // than the time at which the state was created.
   return ScheduledActivity(flowLogicRefFactory.create(HeartbeatFlow::class.java, thisStateRef), nextActivityTime)
```

As a result of this dependency in the ScheduableState (see above), we would have to create the flow in the same CorDapp as in the ContractAndState, which we have decided not to do. Rather, our workaround is to do the scheduling on the spring backend for the time-being.

Currently to add dependencies to the flow CorDapp, you add to the flow CorDapp project, the ContractAndState in the build.gradle. To make the ContractAndState depend on the flow, you can't add the dependency into its build.gradle else it creates a circular reference. The only way we have found is still to add to the ContractAndState CorDapp project the flow that the ScheduableState is dependent on, so its not really working if we follow the template. Are there workarounds or have we not wire-up the dependencies correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special `FlowLogicRefFactory.create` method exactly for this use-case.

You are using `fun create(flowClass: Class<out FlowLogic<*>>, vararg args: Any?): FlowLogicRef`, which requires a `FlowLogic` class.

Instead, you can use `fun create(flowClassName: String, vararg args: Any?): FlowLogicRef`, which takes a fully-qualified class name.

Comment: Hmmm this overloaded function seems to be available for v3.0 and above only? So if you are running v1.0 or v2.0, you are out of luck?

Comment: Also it says a string object, so e.g. 'com.heartbeat.HeartbeatFlow' or do you literally mean the class path i.e. C:\heartbeat\cordapp\src\main\kotlin\com\heartbeat\HeartbeatFlow.kt

Comment: Ah, that should have read "class name" - fixed. Yes, unfortunately this was added in V3.